# PySpark groupby elements with key of their occurence

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark

I have this data in a DATAFRAME:

```
id,col
65475383,acacia
63975914,acacia
65475383,excelsa
63975914,better
```

I want to have a dictionary that will contain the column "word" and every id that is associated with it, something like this:

```
word:key
acacia: 65475383,63975914
excelsa: 65475383
better: 63975914
```

I tried groupBy, but that is a way to aggregate data, how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you intend to have the result as a Python dictionary or as a Dataframe (it is not clear from your question).

However, if you do want a Dataframe then one way to calculate that is:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list

idsByWords = df \
    .groupBy("col") \
    .agg(collect_list("id").alias("ids")) \
    .withColumnRenamed("col", "word")
```

This will result in:

```py
idsByWords.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+-------+--------------------+
|word   |ids                 |
+-------+--------------------+
|excelsa|[65475383]          |
|better |[63975914]          |
|acacia |[65475383, 63975914]|
+-------+--------------------+
```

Then you can turn that dataframe into a Python dictionary :

```py
d = {r.asDict()["word"]: r.asDict()["ids"] for r in idsByWords.collect()}
```

To finally get:

```py
{
   'excelsa': [65475383], 
   'better': [63975914], 
   'acacia': [65475383, 63975914]
}
```

*Note that `collect` may crash your driver program if it exceeds your driver memory.*

Comment: Hi, etherealyn! Thank you for the solution! Yes, my intention is to have a broadcast variable with a dictionary value of above dataframe

Comment: @gammauniversity In that case please check the updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, I see your note at the end, I am not planning to use collect, this dictionary will be used as a broadcast variable as a lookup table